# redirect after login fos user symfony

Tags: symfony-2.1

how to redirect after login with fos user? why my code can't work? 
here my security.yml

```
   main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            # default_target_path:            /home 
            # target_path_parameter:          _target_path
            # use_referer:                    false
        oauth:
            failure_path: /login
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
            oauth_user_provider:
                # service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
                service: project_home_userprovider

        anonymous: ~
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/murid, roles: [ROLE_MURID] }
```

here my routing

```
    murid:
    resource: "@muridBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

admin:
    resource: "@adminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin

home:
    resource: "@homeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix: /login

facebook_login:
    pattern: /login/check-facebook
```

after success login, its always direct to symfony homepage.. cant u help me?? how to redirect to another page with different ROLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will find your solution at her

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html

don't know why but i am not able to post code here so i am posting the URL where i found the answer :) hope it will be help full to you

Comment: He is using FOSUserBundle, not the standard Symfony login form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the **default_target_path**. In case of using OAuth you should define it as well.

```
main:
    form_login:
        default_target_path: "/your-path"
    oauth:
        default_target_path: "/your-path"
```

If you want to change the default_target_path according to the role check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676041/symfony2-fosuserbundle-redirect-after-login-according-to-the-role).