# Symfony2 / FOSUserBundle - Redirect after login according to the role

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to customize the redirection after login according to the user's role.

FYI : I use `symfony 2.8`

I create this class :

```
<?php

namespace Users\UsersBundle\Redirection;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class AfterLoginRedirection implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;
    protected $security;

  /**
   * AfterLoginRedirection constructor.
   * @param Router $router
   * @param Security $security
  */
   public function __construct(Router $router, Security $security)
  {
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->security = $security;
  }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
     public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
  {
    if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('_homepage_admin'));
    } else {
        $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');

        $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);
    }
    return $response;
 }
}
```

I Create this service :

```
services:
redirect.after.login:
    class: Users\UsersBundle\Redirection\AfterLoginRedirection
    arguments: [@router]
```

I modified the firewall

```
    firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            success_handler: redirect.after.login
        logout:
            path:   /users/logout
            target: /
        anonymous:    true
```

And I got this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Users\UsersBundle\Redirection\AfterLoginRedirection::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Users\UsersBundle\Redirection\Router, instance
>   of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\eCommerce\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 2060 and defined

What does i missed ? Any clues or advices ?

Thanks.

Comment: You never inject the $security argument of the class constructor. From where do you want it come?

Comment: Yep i saw that after. So I injected the $security and i had the same error.. Anyway, it's work thanks to Vamsi solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace Users\UsersBundle\Redirection;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

class AfterLoginRedirection implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;
    protected $security;

    /**
     * AfterLoginRedirection constructor.
     * @param Router $router
     * @param AuthorizationChecker $security
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router, AuthorizationChecker $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }


    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('_homepage_admin'));
        } else {
            $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');

            $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**service definition:**

```
redirect.after.login:
        class: Users\UsersBundle\Redirection\AfterLoginRedirection
        arguments: ['@router','@security.authorization_checker']
```

Changes I have made :

- Use `Router` instead of `RouterInterface`
- Inject `@security.authorization_checker` to the
  `redirect.after.login` service

Comment: Interfaces should be used as possible to type-hint the arguments of a service. Here, Router and RouterInterface doesn't make any difference, but it would be more flexible to use the interface in case of custom router. Otherwise, the thing missed by the question's owner was the `security.authorization_checker`, so it would works fine with your answer.